# I can't send email from gmail

Tags: c++, email, curl, gmail

I need to send registration codes to users from my server. I developed some code for this.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <curl/curl.h>

class EmailAddress 
{
public:
    EmailAddress(const char *email)
        : email_{email}
        {
        }

    EmailAddress(const std::string &email)
        : email_{email}
        {
        }

    EmailAddress(const std::string &email, const std::string &displayName)
        : email_{email.empty() ? "" : "<"+email+">"},
          name_{"\"" + displayName + "\""}
        {
        }

    std::string domain() const
        {
            return email_.substr(email_.find('@') + 1);
        }

    explicit operator const char *() const
        {
            return email_.c_str();
        }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddress &email)
        {
            return out << email.name_ << " " << email.email_;
        }

private:
    std::string email_;
    std::string name_;
};

typedef std::vector<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses;
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddresses &emailAddresses);

class Email
{
public:
    Email(const EmailAddress   &from,
          const EmailAddress   &to,
          const std::string    &subject,
          const std::string    &body,
          const EmailAddresses &cc = EmailAddresses())
        : from_{from}
        , to_{to}
        , cc_{cc.empty() ? EmailAddresses(1, to) : cc}
        , subject_{subject}
        , body_{body}
        {
        }

    CURLcode send(const std::string &url,
                  const std::string &userName, 
                  const std::string &password);

private:
    struct StringData {
            std::string msg;
            size_t bytesLeft;
            StringData(std::string &&m) : msg{m}, bytesLeft{msg.size()} {}
            StringData(std::string  &m) = delete;
        };

    static std::string dateTimeNow_();
    static size_t payloadSource_(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
    std::string generateMessageId_() const;
    std::string setPayloadText_();

    EmailAddress from_, to_;
    EmailAddresses cc_;
    std::string subject_, body_;
};


CURLcode Email::send(const std::string &url,
                     const std::string &userName,
                     const std::string &password)
{
    CURLcode ret = CURLE_OK;

    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    StringData textData { setPayloadText_() };

    if (curl) {
        std::ostringstream cc;
        cc << cc_;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME,     userName.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD,     password.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,          url     .c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL,      (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,      "/path/to/certificate.pem");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM,    (const char *)from_);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients,   (const char *)to_);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients,   cc.str().c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT,    recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payloadSource_);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA,     &textData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,       1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,      1L);

        ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (ret != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: "
                      << curl_easy_strerror(ret)
                      << std::endl;
        }

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return ret;
}

std::string Email::dateTimeNow_()
{
    const int RFC5322_TIME_LEN = 32;

    std::string ret;
    ret.resize(RFC5322_TIME_LEN);

    time_t tt;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    time(&tt);
    tm *t = localtime(&tt);
#else
    tm tv, *t = &tv;
    tt = time(&tt);
    localtime_r(&tt, t);
#endif

    strftime(&ret[0], RFC5322_TIME_LEN, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", t);

    return ret;
}

inline std::string Email::generateMessageId_() const
{
    const size_t MESSAGE_ID_LEN = 37;

    tm t;
    time_t tt;
    time(&tt);

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    gmtime_s(&t, &tt);
#else
    gmtime_r(&tt, &t);
#endif

    std::string ret;
    ret.resize(MESSAGE_ID_LEN);
    size_t dateLen = std::strftime(&ret[0], MESSAGE_ID_LEN, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &t);

    static const std::string alphaNum {
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };

    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, alphaNum.length() - 1);

    std::generate_n(ret.begin() + dateLen,
                    MESSAGE_ID_LEN - dateLen,
                    [&]() { return alphaNum[distr(gen)]; });

    return ret;
}

size_t Email::payloadSource_(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    StringData *text = reinterpret_cast<StringData *>(userp);

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size * nmemb) < 1) || (text->bytesLeft == 0)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((nmemb * size) >= text->msg.size()) {
        text->bytesLeft = 0;
        return text->msg.copy(reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr), text->msg.size());
    }

    return 0;
}

std::string Email::setPayloadText_()
{
    std::string ret = "Date: " + dateTimeNow_() + "\r\n";

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "To: "   << to_   << "\r\n"
           "From: " << from_ << "\r\n";

    if (cc_.size() > 1) {
        oss <<   "Cc: "   << cc_   << "\r\n";
    }

    ret += oss.str();

    ret +=
        "Message-ID: <" + generateMessageId_() + "@" + from_.domain() + ">\r\n"
        "Subject: " + subject_ + "\r\n"
        "\r\n" +
        body_ + "\r\n"
        "\r\n";

    return ret;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddresses &emailAddresses)
{
    if (!emailAddresses.empty()) {
        auto it = emailAddresses.begin();
        out << *it;
        while (++it != emailAddresses.end()) {
            out << "," << *it;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

If I use mail.ru service for sending email it works good. But if I use gmail.com  service I get an error:

> - Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:465/
> - Trying 64.233.165.109...
> - Connected to smtp.gmail.com (64.233.165.109) port 465 (#0)
> - response reading failed
> - Closing connection 0
>     curl_easy_perform() failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer

```
Email email({ "...@gmail.com", "Name" },
              "...@gmail.com",
              "Subj",
              "Body");

email.send(   "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:465",
              "...@gmail.com",
              "Password");
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have your SMTP relay turned on for gmail?

Comment: Do you have an App password? You cannot use your normal password because security.

Comment: Last time I did this I had to turn down some of G-mail's internal security (and they changed how to do that recently so I can't give a good answer), and as @Raindrop7 suggests, had to turn on compile in SSL support. Used OpenSSL, but had to do some hackery of the default build scripts to make cURL and OpenSSL play nice on Windows with mingw.

Comment: @user4581301: I remember one day when using gmail through openSSL I had to configured gmail client in my account to be able to send mails

Answer (score 2):

I think that you missed the authentication of server Gmail, here is some configuration for outgoing mails:

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server

```
smtp.gmail.com
Requires SSL: Yes
Requires TLS: Yes (if available)
Requires Authentication: Yes
Port for SSL: 465
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
```

also go to your account and enable IMAP and POP and save changes.

Comment: For 587: curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed sending data to the peer

Comment: @Ufx cURL spits out, or can be configured to spit out, some fairly detailed diagnostics. what development environment and OS are you using?

Comment: @user4581301 now I'm using VS 2015 and Windows 7

Comment: @Ufx mingw compiler?

Comment: @user4581301 MSVC14

Comment: @Ufx rats. Drifting outside what I know. What are you using for SSL/TLS support?

Comment: I didn't understand what do I have to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library for sending mail : http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/

Comment: Can you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322794/i-get-error-when-im-trying-to-send-email-using-libquickmail