# I get error when i'm trying to send email using libquickmail

Tags: c++, email, smtp

When I'm trying to send email using https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail
I get error

> Unable to resolve SMTP server host name.

```
#include "quickmail.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "libquickmaillight.dll.a")

int main()
{
    quickmail_initialize();
    quickmail mailobj = quickmail_create("LOGIN@yandex.ru", "libquickmail test e-mail");
    quickmail_set_body(mailobj, "This is a test e-mail.\nThis mail was sent using libquickmail.");

    const char *errmsg = quickmail_send(mailobj, "smtp.yandex.com", 465, "LOGIN@yandex.ru", "PASSWORD");
    if (errmsg != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending e-mail: %s\n", errmsg);
    }

    quickmail_destroy(mailobj);
}
```

Compiler is MSVC14.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `smtp.yandex.ru` instead of `smtp.yandex.com`?

Comment: Did not help. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **quickmail_send_secure** instead of **quickmail_send**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you are using port 465 wich probably means you want to use SSL encryption.

To use SSL encryption you need to use `quickmail_send_secure()`. As `libquickmaillight` doesn't support encryption you will need to link against `libquickmail` instead.

Your error `Unable to resolve SMTP server host name` indicates a DNS lookup error. Make sure `ping smtp.yandex.com` in a Command Prompt works on your system.

Also the difference between the full and the light library is that the full library uses libcurl. There is a chance not building against `libquickmaillight` may also fix your DNS issue as libcurl may be better at looking up DNS stuff (e.g. when you're using IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. visual Studio 2015 enterprise.
The solution for a program in WINDOWS was WSAStartup :
The WSAStartup function initiates use of the Winsock DLL by a process.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup

Before the use of libquickmail:

```
    WSADATA data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
```

.....

and
WSACleanup();
at the end